# Android Timer is called twice

Tags: android, timer, timertask

**Hey guys**

I'm trying to develop a little slide show in android. I've implemented the timer with a timertask and as expected the "run"-method is called everytime after the delay. But, however, when the delaytime has passed, the run method is called twice, so that the slide show slides two pictures instead of one.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Heres some code for better understandig what i've done.

```
public void startTimer() {
    if(timer == null) {
        timer = new Timer();
    }

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            timerHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("Hier herein", "Timer abgelaufen");

                }   
            }); 
        }
    }, 7000, 7000); 
}
```

The startTimer()-Method is only called once, so I really don't understand, why the function is called twice.
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I will recommend you to use ViewFlipper which is a ready made slideShow control in android.

Comment: ged rid of Timer/TimerTask, just use timerHandler with postDelayed

Comment: Okay, i will try this, jibran ;) but I have to use timers later on in my app again, so I'm very interested in the fact, why the run method is called twice...

Comment: solution from pskink worked for me ;) Very much thanks :)

Comment: I suppose the behaviour you're seeing is per design. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html): *"With **fixed-rate execution**, the start time of each successive run of a task is scheduled without regard for when the previous run took place. **This may result in a series of bunched-up runs (one launched immediately after another)** if delays prevent the timer from starting tasks on time."*