# Android Service scheduleTaskExecutor will be calles two times

Tags: android, service

I am programming an **Android** Application. There is a service and scheduleTaskExecutor which calls a method reducing hours and minutes every minute. Do you know why scheduleTaskExecutor executes two times every minute? Or why if/else will be ignored sometimes? There should be a beginning delay and a delay of executing of 1 minute... Thanks!

```
/**
 * Set reduce time thread
 */

public void setRunTime() {
    // counting work
    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            reduceTime();

        }
    }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

/**
 * Reduce time
 * 
 */
public void reduceTime() {

    if (this.getHour() != 0) {

        if (this.getMinute() == 0) {

            // set Minute
            this.setMinute(60);

            Log.i("test1", this.getHour() + " " + this.getMinute());

            // reduce hour
            this.setHour(getHour() - 1);

            // Reduce time
            this.setMinute(getMinute() - 1);

            Log.i("test2", this.getHour() + " " + this.getMinute());

        } else {

            // Reduce time
            this.setMinute(getMinute() - 1);

            Log.i("test3", this.getHour() + " " + this.getMinute());
        }

    } else if (this.getHour() == 0 && this.getMinute() != 0) {
        this.setMinute(getMinute() - 1);

    } else {
        this.scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdown();
        this.stopSelf(getStartId());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer:**

Use a handler. There are problems with Timer and ExecuterService.

See this link:

[Android Timer is called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769341/android-timer-is-called-twice)